# i include footer.php file on my page , but the bootstrap is changing my footer how i can to include my footer without conflicts bootstrap.css

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

on the footer file i have style on the header  balise.***how i can fix footer included without changing anythig***

`enter code here`

```
     <head>
         <?php include( '../../footer.php');?>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
         <script src=" js/jquery.js"></script>
         <script src="js/bootstrap.js"> </script>
         <script src="js/myjs.js"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?1234">
         <style>
         body {
             background: #F4F6F9;
         }
         </style>
         <title>Admin</title>
     </head>
```

Comment: You mean you want to use your footer without styles of bootstrap? Bootstrap works with classes, right? Are you using any Bootstrap classes on your footer? And it might help if you'd show the actual HTML of the footer.

Comment: @azboch can you please show the content of `footer.php`?

Comment: i cant put them have more 6k carracter but its working normaly cuz i include them on ther files and its good jst on the file have  bootstrap he changed

Comment: @EmielZuurbier yes u right i want to use footer without styles of bootstrap

Comment: on the footer.php its like thats form ,

<html>
head
<style>
my style footer
</style>
</head>
<div>
my footer content .
</div>
</html>
i use them without link its style on the same file